# The "chunk" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-sdk-nodejs, nodejs-stream, nodejs-server

I'm running the following code and it fails with the below error.

AWS Code to list all objects inside a bucket.

```
const http = require('http');
const host = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 5000;
const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');
const fs = require('fs');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');



const laptopDate = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/data/data.json`, `utf-8`));

AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: '***', secretAccessKey: '***', region: 'ap-south-1'});
s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'});

var params = { 
    Bucket: 'bucket-name'
};

const server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
    const path = url.parse(req.url, true).pathname;
    const id = url.parse(req.url, true).query.id;

    if (path === 'bucket' || path === '/')
      s3.listObjects(params, function (err, data) {
        if(err) throw err;
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
        //const output = JSON.parse(data)
        console.log(data);
        res.end(data);
      });
});

server.listen(port, host, function(req, res) {
    console.log(`Server is listening on ${host} and ${port}`)
});
```

The first output which is console.log displays everything as expected.
However the res.end to render the output to the screen fails with the below error.

```
The "chunk" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer. Received an instance of Object
    at ServerResponse.end (_http_outgoing.js:752:13)
    at Response.<anonymous> (D:\js\Extra\starter\index.js:30:13)
    at Request.<anonymous> (D:\js\Extra\starter\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:364:18)
    at Request.callListeners (D:\js\Extra\starter\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (D:\js\Extra\starter\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (D:\js\Extra\starter\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:683:14)
    at Request.transition (D:\js\Extra\starter\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (D:\js\Extra\starter\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:14:12)
    at D:\js\Extra\starter\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (D:\js\Extra\starter\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:38:9) {
  message: 'The "chunk" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer. Received an instance of Object',
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE',
  time: 2020-05-18T08:39:24.916Z
}
```

Comment: If the response from S3 is an object, then just try  -> `res.json(data)`

Comment: I think it is probably good idea to remove AWS config params from this question :)

Comment: it fails even if i use res.json

*************
D:\js\Extra\starter\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:31
            throw err;
            ^

Error [TypeError]: res.json is not a function
    at Response.<anonymous> (D:\js\Extra\starter\index.js:30:13)
    at Request.<anonymous> (D:\js\Extra\starter\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib

Comment: @LazarNikolic, That was not the actual value of the AWS Keys ;-). Else by now i would have had multiple M# Large VM's running on my AWS Account:-)

Answer (score 39):

Remove this `res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });`

And instead of `res.end(data)` use `res.send(data)` or better yet `res.send({ data })`.

---

**EDIT**
I didn't notice that you didn't use express, try this:

```
res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
res.write(JSON.stringify(data));
res.end();
```

Comment: Still fails, message: 'res.send is not a function',
  code: 'TypeError',
  time: 2020-05-18T12:59:37.706Z
}

Note I'm not using Express

Comment: It still fails --> The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer. Received an instance of Object

Comment: Sorry, do this `res.write(JSON.stringify(data));`

Comment: That works Perfectly. Could you please explain why we used JSON.stringify and when should i use it and other methods available??

Comment: It's because `data`'s data type is an `object/json`, and `res.write()` accepts data type `string` or `buffer`. `JSON.stringify` converts the `object` to a `string` basically.

Answer (score 13):

In case this may help someone, try to use the objectMode property.

something like it

```
const t = new Transform({
    objectMode: true, // set this one to true
    transform(data, _, done) {
      //...your code
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

In case this may help someone, I was using data type other than `String`, `Number` to be exact, so I changed it to `String` to resolve this error

Answer (score 2):

In case of ExpressJS, the following solution worked for me:

```js
const response = await s3client.send(command);
// The Body object also has 'transformToByteArray' and 'transformToWebStream' methods.
const data = await response.Body.transformToByteArray()
const buffer = Buffer.from(data);       
res.attachment(`filename.pdf`).contentType("application/pdf").send(buffer)
```