# Forge Design Automation Revit Tutorial Error

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I am trying the Design Automation Tutorial for Revit.
I am getting the following error.
Can someone help me fix this error.

[image]

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "chunk" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received an instance of ReadStream
at new NodeError (c:\Users\roshan.kerketta\Desktop\Digital\Forge\ModelDesignAutomation\SampleDesignAutomation\lib\internal\errors.js:372:5)
at write_ (c:\Users\roshan.kerketta\Desktop\Digital\Forge\ModelDesignAutomation\SampleDesignAutomation\lib\_http_outgoing.js:742:11)
at ClientRequest.end (c:\Users\roshan.kerketta\Desktop\Digital\Forge\ModelDesignAutomation\SampleDesignAutomation\lib\_http_outgoing.js:855:5)
at Request._end (c:\Users\roshan.kerketta\Desktop\Digital\Forge\ModelDesignAutomation\SampleDesignAutomation\node_modules\superagent\lib\node\index.js:1282:9)
at Request.end (c:\Users\roshan.kerketta\Desktop\Digital\Forge\ModelDesignAutomation\SampleDesignAutomation\node_modules\superagent\lib\node\index.js:1000:8)
at c:\Users\roshan.kerketta\Desktop\Digital\Forge\ModelDesignAutomation\SampleDesignAutomation\node_modules\superagent\lib\request-base.js:282:12
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at RequestBase.then (c:\Users\roshan.kerketta\Desktop\Digital\Forge\ModelDesignAutomation\SampleDesignAutomation\node_modules\superagent\lib\request-base.js:264:31)
at c:\Users\roshan.kerketta\Desktop\Digital\Forge\ModelDesignAutomation\SampleDesignAutomation\node_modules\forge-apis\src\ApiClient.js:394:7
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE', statusCode: undefined, stack: 'TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "chunk"…ions (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)', message: 'The "chunk" argument must be of type string …nt8Array. Received an instance of ReadStream', toString: ƒ, …}
```

Comment: There isn't enough information to help you with this question. Kindly share more details on which tutorial you are using (at this point there are many tutorials). I'd also suggest to go though the instructions and see what you might have missed. This may turn out to be something basic and esential that you missed.

Comment: @RahulBhobe I used the following tutorial [link](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/modifymodels). I want to understand what the error means, so it could help me fix the error., though it might be basic.

Comment: @JohnKuldeepRoshanKerketta, I tried with the tutorial sample, it works well. My test is uploaded to https://myshare.autodesk.com/:v:/g/personal/xiaodong_liang_autodesk_com/EXopNPtwmNhPkrjI4j4xiqcBfKOWNXf250kyFcnT8t5nQQ?e=NCkQPD

Comment: @JohnKuldeepRoshanKerketta The error in your test shows chunk , but the tutorial does not nothing with chunk. It is direct uploading of whole file. So I guess you are trying to add some of your own code to upload big file in chunk? Could you clarify and share us with demo code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Rahul for spotting the issue! I can reproduce what @JohnKuldeepRoshanKerketta  experienced in Forge SDK (forge-apis) in 0.9.0. By the hint of error, I updated the [tutorial code(line 509,510)](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.designautomation/blob/nodejs/routes/DesignAutomation.js#L508-L511) to use readFile, instead of file stream. Now it works well with 0.9.0.

I posted the Issue with tutorial
https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.designautomation/issues/31

```js
// 2. upload inputFile
const inputFileNameOSS = `${new Date().toISOString().replace(/[-T:\.Z]/gm, '').substring(0,14)}_input_${_path.basename(req.file.originalname)}`; // avoid overriding

try {
    //let contentStream = _fs.createReadStream(req.file.path);

    let fileContent = _fs.readFileSync(req.file.path);

    await new ForgeAPI.ObjectsApi().uploadObject(bucketKey, inputFileNameOSS, req.file.size, fileContent, {}, req.oauth_client, req.oauth_token);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to understand what the error means, so it could help me fix the error., though it might be basic.

If your goal is to understand this specific error, then you can read this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61869307/11057988) where it is best asked/explained. However since this is coming from Forge's `nodejs` apis, I think you did not write this code and you should not be concerned with it.

My best guess is you have somehow managed to upgrade the `nodejs` package `forge-api` to `0.9.0` and the rest of the tutorial repo/code is not compatible with it. You can check this with the following command:

```
cd {repo_folder}
npm ls -depth=0
```

You should see the following result:

```
├── autodesk.forge.designautomation@3.0.5
├── body-parser@1.20.0
├── cookie-session@1.4.0
├── express@4.18.1
├── forge-apis@0.8.6
├── form-data@4.0.0
├── multer@1.4.4
└── socket.io@4.5.1
```

If your `forge-apis` is showing `0.9.0` instead of `0.8.6`, then it explains the error you have. To downgrade it, you can either delete your `node_modules` folder, undo any changes to `package.json` and/or `package-lock.json` and run `npm install` again.

Alternatively you can also explicitly downgrade the `forge-api` module.

```
cd {repo_folder}
npm install forge-apis@0.8.6 -save
npm ls -depth=0
```