# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "chunk" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array node.js

Tags: node.js, filesystems

The example in W3 School [Node.js File System Module](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_filesystem.asp)
is giving this error on my machine:

```
node:_http_outgoing:791
throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(
^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "chunk" argument must be of type string or an             instance of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received undefined
←[90m    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:377:5)←[39m
←[90m    at write_ (node:_http_outgoing:791:11)←[39m
←[90m    at ServerResponse.write (node:_http_outgoing:756:15)←[39m
at ReadFileContext.callback (C:\Proyectos\myfirst.js:6:9)
←[90m    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterOp
```

I have installed
Node.js v18.3.0 and write down exactly as the page with copy paste.
I have checke related (similar) answers and do not provide a solution in my case.

Code:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
fs.readFile('demofile1.html', function(err, data) {
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
res.write(data);
return res.end();
  });
}).listen(8080);
```

html:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>My Header</h1>
<p>My paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add your code to your question.

Comment: @AbdurrahimAhmadov I placed a link to the code but anyway I will added here.
Is the same of w3school link

Comment: I think a similar question in this situation was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61865764/the-chunk-argument-must-be-of-type-string-or-an-instance-of-buffer). Did you look at that?

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error. Got it fixed by running the command from the same folder where demofile.html is located. When I run it with node node-learning/test.js, I guess it can't find demofile.html