# When I used Postman to add value into my student object array? It gave me the error like this

Tags: javascript, node.js, postman

Could someone have any solution to solve this error?

I used Postman to add new student into students, but when it ran to req.on("data", function (chunk) {…}. It gave me the error which is like below.

create server or import library code which is like http, url,... I already wrote them in my code. The problem here is this function.

Thanks everyone due to watch my post.

```
function addStudent(req, res) {
    var body = "";

    req.on("data", function (chunk) {   // error from this line
        body += chunk;
    });

    req.on("end", function () {
        var post = url.parse("/?" + body, true);

        let name = post.query.name;
        let gender = post.query.gender;

        students.push({ name: name, gender: gender });
    });

    res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "application/json" });
    return res.end({ success: "true" });
}
```

```
node:_http_outgoing:802
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "chunk" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received an instance of Object
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:387:5)
    at write_ (node:_http_outgoing:802:11)
    at ServerResponse.end (node:_http_outgoing:934:5)
    at addStudent (D:\TDTU\Third_Year\HK1\Advanced_Web_Programming\Tasks\DAY2\520H0549\exercise3.js:27:13)
    at Server.<anonymous> (D:\TDTU\Third_Year\HK1\Advanced_Web_Programming\Tasks\DAY2\520H0549\exercise3.js:40:12)
    at Server.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at parserOnIncoming (node:_http_server:1013:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (node:_http_common:117:17) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error above shows that you're trying to assign an object to a string

In your case, you defined the `var body` to be a type of string,
while in your callback function, an `object` was received.

to fix that, if you're unsure of the type of data/argument you'll be receiving in your callback,
you can set the `var body` to be type any, like the code below;

```
    function addStudent(req, res) {
    var body = []; //this will set the data type to any, so you can push in any datatype/argument to it.

    req.on("data", function (chunk) {   // error from this line
        body.push(...chunk);
    });

    req.on("end", function () {
        var post = url.parse("/?" + body, true);

        let name = post.query.name;
        let gender = post.query.gender;

        students.push({ name: name, gender: gender });
    });
res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "application/json" });
return res.end({ success: "true" });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my post. But it didn't work. I did remove like you said, but it still gave that error

Comment: how about you assign the body as an new object instead of appending it, since from your code about the body object doesn't exist before within the function. like example, body = chunk or use body.push(...chunk)

Comment: have edited the above code to use object destructuring method

Comment: it's still the same.

Comment: I will give you a picture which shows how I use postman to send data

Comment: alright, i will be expecting

Comment: here https://ibb.co/9yBhfcP

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I think I already solved the problem in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61865764/the-chunk-argument-must-be-of-type-string-or-an-instance-of-buffer

Comment: orh i see, you're welcome

Comment: I made it. But simply, I just use res.write(JSON.stringify({ success: "true" })) instead of res.end({ success: true}). And it worked

Comment: alright that was cool one. but why not using express? it can be much simpler and easier

Comment: I know. But it is my homework request in advanced web programming class. So I must use nodejs to solve the problem without using any module installed by package manager