# Get data sent from http request in laravel

Tags: node.js, request, decode

How to get data from https request method in laravel. My received data is currently

```
{"{\"email\":68,\"token\":\"945672295777710090\"}":null}.\\dd(Request $request)
```

I don't know how to decode them properly. Or did I send the data the wrong way. I tried some common way `$request->input`, `$request->all`, `$request->email`, `jsondecode, endcode`

Here is the client side code:

```
    var post_data = JSON.stringify({
        email: email,
        token: token
    });
    var post_options = {
        host: host_main,
        port: '443',
        path: new_user_list,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(post_data)
        }
    };

    var post_req = http.request(post_options, function(res) {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            console.log(chunk);
        });
    });

    post_req.write(post_data);
    post_req.end();
```

Comment: can you try sending the data in JSON only?

Comment: I don't know what is laravel and what you're doing wrong, if anything, but you can easily parse that string in node/js with `const str = '{"{\"email\":68,\"token\":\"945672295777710090\"}":null}.\\dd(Request $request)'; const res = JSON.parse(str.split('.')[0])`

Comment: sorry I not really  understand  @SohailAnsari

Comment: {"{\"email\":68,\"token\":\"945672295777710090\"}":null}. is the data received from \\dd(Request $request) in laravel. dd() it's like printing out a value for debugging @JoãoPimentelFerreira

Comment: dont JSON.stringify the data, send them as is. `var post_data = {email: email,token: token};`

Comment: it will send me an error :``` code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
. The "chunk" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received an instance of Object```, and i don't get any response from serve looks like it crashed in js trying to send json code
@N69S

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The "chunk" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61865764/the-chunk-argument-must-be-of-type-string-or-an-instance-of-buffer)

Comment: I also don't use ```Express ```. Their then method is the same as I am using now @N69S

Answer (score 0):

If you are in control of laravel side as well, than you should format your data before sending, something like `json_encode($data)` and than your response will be in JSON format.

Or you can do this with response:

```
 stringData.replace("\", "")
 JSON.parse(stringData)
```

Comment: the data ```chuck``` received is actually $request I received at the server, I don't need to send the data back to the client for processing. I need something like jsondecode("{\"email\":68,\"token\":\"945672295777710090\"}":null}") on the server side to process that string

Comment: Excuse me if I don't understand very well but I have to ask, your server is in laravel, and client in node? And you need  to parse this data in laravel?

Comment: Yes, sorry for my poor english. that's really what i need to do

Comment: Ok, so since you are sending request data as a string, and in laravel backend you get string data, did you try to parse_str($data) ?

Comment: parse_str returns me an empty result